# Cannot read from a closed TextReader

Tags: c#, .net-2.0

I've got a system that processes some large CSV files.

The scenario has now arisen where these files might have a number of none-delimited, worthless lines preceding the actual comma-delimited content.

The approach I have taken is to create a temporary reader to ascertain the number of superfluous lines and then move the working TextReader on that number of lines ready to be processed.

My code is as follows:

```
private static TextReader PrepareReader(TextReader reader)
    {
        // Variables
        TextReader tmpReader = reader;
        Int32 superfluousLineCount = 0;

        // Determine how many useless lines we have
        using (tmpReader)
        {
            string line;
            string headerIdentifier = "&1,";
            while ((line = tmpReader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Check if the line starts with the header row identifier
                if (line.Substring(0, 3) != headerIdentifier)
                {
                    // Increment the superfluous line counter
                    superfluousLineCount++;
                }
                else
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        // Move the source reader through how many lines we want to ignore
        using (reader)
        {
            for (int i = superfluousLineCount; i > 0; i--)
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        // Return
        return reader;
    }
```

However, the `reader.ReadLine();` in this part of the code:

```
for (int i = superfluousLineCount; i > 0; i--)
{
reader.ReadLine();
}
```

...throws the following exception

> Cannot read from a closed TextReader.
>   ObjectDisposedException in mscorlib
>   Method:
>     Void ReaderClosed()
>
> Stack Trace:
>   at System.IO.__Error.ReaderClosed()
>   at System.IO.StreamReader.ReadLine()
>   at CsvReader.PrepareReader(TextReader reader) in CsvReader.cs:line 93

Any advice greatly appreciated.  Also, is the best way to go about my challenge?

Notes: Framework 2.0

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you are using `using (tmpReader)` it will close `tmpReader` (Which references the same object as `reader` does), so when you try to read from `reader` in your loop, it is closed.

Your best bet is to combine the two loops.  Sine you only want to skip lines, I would think the logic of the first loop is sufficient.

Comment: Right.  This line `TextReader tmpReader = reader;` is completely meaningless.

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense now it's been pointed out.  Is tehre a way to *copy* a TextReader without interrogating the file again?

Comment: Check out [this SO thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831417/how-do-you-reset-a-c-sharp-net-textreader-cursor-back-to-the-start-point) for what you could try

Answer (score 0):

I think you simply have to do this (normalize/correct it, i made some simplifications without any compile or test):

```
    // edit
    private static TextReader PrepareReader(TextReader reader, out string outLine)
    {



            string line;
            string headerIdentifier = "&1,";
            while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                // Check if the line starts with the header row identifier
                if (line.Substring(0, 3) != headerIdentifier)
                {
                    // ... do nothing
                }
                else
                {
                    // edit
                    outLine = line;
                    break;
                }
            }

    }
```

IOW use the input reference, and move the reader where you want to.

**Be aware to close your reader** outside this method

Comment: But with this, won't I already have passed the first line that I will want to process?