# How to reset position in StringReader to begining of String?

Tags: c#, stringreader

I have the following code:

```
StringReader contentReader = new StringReader(this.dataContent.ToString());
```

After I parse my DataContent, I need to reset the poistion of the contentReader to begining of the string. How do I do it? I dont see a set poistion option in StringReader

Comment: Just for curiosity, why you need to reposition it to the start?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Set it to a new instance of StringReader.  I don't believe you can change the position of an existing one.

> contentReader = new StringReader(this.dataContent.ToString());

Answer (score 5):

Another option would be to load the string into a `MemoryStream` then use a `StreamReader` to iterate over it.  `MemoryStream` definitely supports position resets on a memory stream.

```
String data = "Hello! My name it Inigo Montoya.";
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        // Do your parsing here using the standard StreamReader methods.
        // They should be fairly comparable to StringReader.

        // When all done, reset stream position to the beginning.
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    }
}
```

Comment: You **must** call `reader.DiscardBufferedData()` after setting the stream position. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.discardbuffereddata(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @StevenLiekens: `reader.Flush()` is another option.  However, both of these methods are only needed if the stream has been written to.  In this instance neither call is needed.

Comment: There is no `StreamReader.Flush()`. Only `DiscardBufferedData()`. Which you have to call after seeking, because the reader will read any buffered bytes before hitting the stream again if you don't.

Answer (score 3):

The StringReader keeps track of its position within the string with a private `int` field called `_pos`, if you want to reset it you can use a simple extension method like this:

```
public static void Reset(this StringReader reader)
{
    reader.GetType()
          .GetField("_pos", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance)
          .SetValue(reader, 0);
}
```

And a test method:

```
[Test]
public void Reset()
{
    const string random = "this is a test string";
    using(var reader = new StringReader(random))
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(random, reader.ReadToEnd());
        Assert.IsEmpty(reader.ReadToEnd());

        reader.Reset();
        Assert.AreEqual(random, reader.ReadToEnd());
        Assert.IsEmpty(reader.ReadToEnd());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension method for the StreamReader and handle it by yourself:

```
public static class SRExtentions
{
    public static void ResetToBeginning(this StringReader reader)
    {
        SetPrivateField(reader, "_pos", 0);
    }

    private static void SetPrivateField(this object obj, string name, object value)
    {
        BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
        Type type = obj.GetType();
        FieldInfo field = type.GetField(name, flags);
        field.SetValue(obj, value);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

See also a similar question :
[How do you reset a C# .NET TextReader cursor back to the start point?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831417/how-do-you-reset-a-c-sharp-net-textreader-cursor-back-to-the-start-point)

But as Matthew said, the solution is probably to simply create a new one.