# Why does reseting a StreamReader does not allow to re-read string in UTF8?

Tags: c#

Reseting a StreamReader leads to strange behaviour. The first assert succeeds whereas the second fails. To correct it one (bad) solution consists in reseting to position 3 instead of 0: sr.BaseStream.Position = 3;

```html
using (var sr = new StreamReader(@"c:\temp\test.txt", Encoding.UTF8)) // test.txt is encoded in UTF8
{
     var read = sr.ReadLine();
     Assert.AreEqual("fromfile", read); // ok
     sr.BaseStream.Position = 0;
     sr.DiscardBufferedData();
     read = sr.ReadLine();
     Assert.AreEqual("fromfile", read); //fails
}
```

Comment: What *does* it contain? You are resetting the *stream*, not the *reader*. Could it be that the first 3 bytes are the BOM and the *reader* automatically skips it?

Comment: Yes, I assume something like that is happening (but I wish I understood better). It was Jon Skeet's suggestion is this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831417/how-do-you-reset-a-c-sharp-net-textreader-cursor-back-to-the-start-point/831436?noredirect=1#comment45980418_831436

Comment: Have you tried commenting out either the `sr.BaseStream.Position` __or__ the `sr.DiscaredBufferedData();` lines to see which is causing your problem? Perhaps it's one or the other, or maybe the combination is causing an issue.

Comment: As an aside, this problem is yet another excellent demonstration of why misusing the BOM as a marker for UTF-8 is a bad idea and not recommended by the Unicode standard. If the file is under your control, consider not using a BOM and assume all files you read are UTF-8 unless proven otherwise.

Comment: @krillgar: commenting out sr.DiscaredBufferedData(); does not help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just didn't manage to *truly* reset the object.  There's a private field in the class named `_checkPreamble`.  It will be set to *false* since it was already checked.  You can hack it:

```
using System.Reflection;
...
     var fi = typeof(StreamReader).GetField("_checkPreamble", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
     fi.SetValue(sr, true);
     read = sr.ReadLine();
     Assert.AreEqual("fromfile", read); // okay now
```

Of course you don't really want to write code like this.  The solution is very trivial, just create a new StreamReader object.

Comment: Or, if the OP is certain the file contains a BOM, just call `sr.Read();`

Comment: @Hans: Yes this works. My conclusion is that you cannot reset the object properly, it's simply not meant to be used liked that.

Comment: @Hans: another way could be (but still not clean): `sr.BaseStream.Position = sr.CurrentEncoding.GetPreamble().Length; `

Comment: No, major fail whale if the file does not in fact contain a BOM.  Which is quite common, *nix programmers insist that it isn't necessary.  Mostly because their shell tends to fall over pretty badly when it does, the shebang problem.